# Changing MongoDB Oplog size

Tags: replication, mongodb

while loading data to mongodb, I keep getting "error RS102 too stale to catch up"... After research I found that my default oplog size for a 32 bit linux machine is too small. I would like it to be 300 mb.. Does anyone know the step to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oplog defaults to 5% of free space on Linux, so I suspect you didn't have a lot available.  To resize your oplog you need to follow the procedure outlined here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/

Answer (score 0):

> **MongoDB version 3.6 +**

In the MongoDB `version 3.6` it is easier to change the oplog size on runtime without restart.

**Check current oplog size**

```
use local
db.oplog.rs.stats().maxSize
```

**To change the oplog size to 300 MB**

```
db.adminCommand({replSetResizeOplog: 1, size: 300})
```

> **MongoDB version less than 3.6**

For older versions you have to follow below steps:

Shutdown the primary server

```
use admin

db.shutdownServer()
```

Start primary as standalone & run on different port say 37017

Login to mongo in port 37017

```
mongo --port 37017
```

Remove the old contents in local database

For safety have backop of old oplog before dropping

```
mongodump --db local --collection 'oplog.rs' --port 37017
```

Drop the old contents in local database

```
use local

db.oplog.rs.drop()

db.me.drop()

db.replset.election.drop()

db.replset.minvalid.drop()

db.startup_log.drop()
```

Replset collection cannot be dropped so remove it with required id :

```
db.system.replset.remove({ "_id" : "your_replsetname"})
```

Create a new oplog of required size say 300 MB

```
db.runCommand( { create: "oplog.rs", capped: true, size: (300 * 1024 * 1024) } )
```

Also you can specify the oplog size in MB in mongod.conf file,say for 300 MB :

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: 300
```

Hope this helps !!!